# Error ILIKE on PostgreSQL

Tags: php, postgresql, codeigniter-2

I've a project that use PostgreSQL and new with it. Below is the error that i was facing. I also has searched on google but cannot find the solution.

> Fatal error: Call to undefined method CI_DB_postgre_driver::ilike() in D:\htdocs\poes\system\application\rapyd\classes\datafilter.php on line 162

I'm using codeigniter framework. This code is from datafilter.php `$this->db->ilike($name, $value);` On my controller,

```
$query1 = "SELECT DISTINCT users.* FROM users LEFT JOIN login ON users.user_id=login.login_user_id;";
$filter->db->query($query1);
$filter->name = new inputField("Name :", "user_name");
$filter->name->clause = "ilike";
```

Comment: What framework are you using?

Comment: Can you show the code that generated the error? `ILIKE` is perfectly legal SQL but not likely a function, unless you defined that yourself.

Comment: @JoeLove i'm using codeigniter

Comment: `ILIKE` is a PostgreSQL extension, probably not supported by your ORM/DBAL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just solve the issue, need to add this function in system/database/DB_active_rec.php to use ilike

```
function ilike($field, $match = '', $side = 'both')
{
    return $this->_ilike($field, $match, 'AND ', $side);
}

function _ilike($field, $match = '', $type = 'AND ', $side = 'both', $not = '')
{
if ( ! is_array($field))
{
$field = array($field => $match);
}

  foreach ($field as $k => $v)
  {
$k = $this->_protect_identifiers($k);

$prefix = (count($this->ar_like) == 0) ? '' : $type;

$v = $this->escape_like_str($v);

if ($side == 'before')
{
$like_statement = $prefix." $k $not ILIKE '%{$v}'";
  }
  elseif ($side == ‘after’)
  {
$like_statement = $prefix." $k $not ILIKE '{$v}%'";
  }
  else
  {
$like_statement = $prefix." $k $not ILIKE '%{$v}%'";
  }

  // some platforms require an escape sequence definition for ILIKE wildcards
  if ($this->_like_escape_str != ‘’)
  {
$like_statement = $like_statement.sprintf($this->_like_escape_str, $this->_like_escape_chr);
}

  $this->ar_like[] = $like_statement;
  if ($this->ar_caching === TRUE)
  {
$this->ar_cache_ilike[] = $like_statement;
$this->ar_cache_exists[] = 'ilike';
}

  }
  return $this;
}
```

source from https://ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/87725/#808269

Answer (score 0):

like this

```
$param = "%".urldecode($this->uri->segment(4))."%";
            if(!empty($this->uri->segment(4))){
                $this->db->where("name ilike",$param); 
             }
```

Comment: Write down what have you changed... the answer can be better that way!